# How to disable reloading or refresh button in browser in flutter web?

Tags: flutter-web

I have an exam with a timer inside a widget I want to prevent users from reloading or show a confirmation dialog

Comment: Hi  Abdelrahman have you get any solution to stop the refresh buttton

Comment: I didn't find a solution but I found that I can excute some code before reloading so I saved the data on shared pref before reloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution but I found that I can excute some code before reloading:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
html.window.onUnload.listen((event) async {
  print('Reloaded');
  
});
```