# How to prevent user to refresh page locally in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a project that need to prevent user to refresh page with some conditions using flutter for web.

I already search and try the solution in this [How to disable reloading or refresh button in browser in flutter web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65826799/how-to-disable-reloading-or-refresh-button-in-browser-in-flutter-web)

but i'm failed to cancel the refresh action.

here is my code to handling

```
html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async {
    if(true){
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Is there a way to cancel the refresh action?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) library:

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

...
bool condition = true;

@override
  void initState() {
    html.window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) {
      if (condition) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
      }
      return null;
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Where `condition` is the condition for blocking the reload.